# Combine (binding columns) two objects with different classes

Tags: r, object, matrix, types, cbind

I want to combine the results of 2 objects in R that have same name for each level. I have wf1 object and `CI1` object (below) but when I use the `cbind` command to combine them I don't get all the columns from wf1 object. The results of `cbind` is at the end of the code. It replaces object name as the column name and removes one of the columns which is "SE" from `wf1`.

```
wf1<-svytotal(~factor(var1)+Total, mydesign)
wf1
                 total      SE
  factor(var1)0  62469  7620.4
  factor(var1)1 151486  9421.3
  Total           213955 13418.5

CI1<-confint(wf1)
CI1
                    2.5 %    97.5 %
  factor(var1)0  47532.84  77404.17
  factor(var1)1 133020.75 169951.38
  Total           187654.80 240254.33

cbind(wf1, CI1)
                     wf1     2.5 %    97.5 %
  factor(var1)0  62468.5  47532.84  77404.17
  factor(var1)1 151486.1 133020.75 169951.38
  Total           213954.6 187654.80 240254.33
```

I want the end result to be like this:

```
                    total       SE      2.5 %     97.5 %
  factor(var1)0      2469  7620.4   47532.84  77404.17
  factor(var1)1    151486  9421.3   133020.75 169951.38
  Total            213955  13418.5  187654.80 240254.33
```

What went wrong here?

This is the results of `dput(wf1)` and `dput(CI1)`:

```
wf1 <- structure(c(`factor(Dummy1)0` = 62468.5031180821, 
                   `factor(Dummy1)1` = 151486.062913796, 
                   Total = 213954.566031878), 
                 var = structure(c(58070142.8887675, 16612955.6715334, 
                                   74683098.560301, 16612955.6715334, 
                                   88759974.1026789, 105372929.774212, 
                                   74683098.560301, 105372929.774212, 
                                   180056028.334513 ), 
                                 .Dim = c(3L, 3L), 
                                 means = c(62468.5031180821, 
                                           151486.062913796, 
                                           213954.566031878)), 
                 statistic = "total", class = "svrepstat")


CI1 <- structure(c(47532.8390009755, 133020.749879858, 187654.797624822, 
                   77404.1672351886, 169951.375947734, 240254.334438934), 
                 .Dim = 3:2, 
                 .Dimnames = list( c("factor(Dummy1)0", 
                                     "factor(Dummy1)1", 
                                     "Total"), 
                                   c("2.5 %", "97.5 %")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `wf1` from `"svrepstat"` to a `"data.frame"`:

```r
library(survey)

class(wf1)
#> [1] "svrepstat"
class(CI1)
#> [1] "matrix" "array"

cbind(as.data.frame(wf1), CI1)
#>                    total        SE     2.5 %    97.5 %
#> factor(Dummy1)0  62468.5  7620.377  47532.84  77404.17
#> factor(Dummy1)1 151486.1  9421.251 133020.75 169951.38
#> Total           213954.6 13418.496 187654.80 240254.33
```

If you want to rename the `rownames`, you can do so by assigning the output of `cbind` to a variable and changing them for that; same goes for the `colnames`:

```r
out <- cbind(as.data.frame(wf1), CI1)

rownames(out) <- c("0", "1", "Total")
colnames(out) <- c("Total", "S.E.", "2.5%", "97.5%")

out
#>          Total      S.E.      2.5%     97.5%
#> 0      62468.5  7620.377  47532.84  77404.17
#> 1     151486.1  9421.251 133020.75 169951.38
#> Total 213954.6 13418.496 187654.80 240254.33
```

##### Data:

```
wf1 <- structure(c(`factor(Dummy1)0` = 62468.5031180821, 
                   `factor(Dummy1)1` = 151486.062913796, 
                   Total = 213954.566031878), 
                 var = structure(c(58070142.8887675, 16612955.6715334, 
                                   74683098.560301, 16612955.6715334, 
                                   88759974.1026789, 105372929.774212, 
                                   74683098.560301, 105372929.774212, 
                                   180056028.334513 ), 
                                 .Dim = c(3L, 3L), 
                                 means = c(62468.5031180821, 
                                           151486.062913796, 
                                           213954.566031878)), 
                 statistic = "total", class = "svrepstat")


CI1 <- structure(c(47532.8390009755, 133020.749879858, 187654.797624822, 
                   77404.1672351886, 169951.375947734, 240254.334438934), 
                 .Dim = 3:2, 
                 .Dimnames = list( c("factor(Dummy1)0", 
                                     "factor(Dummy1)1", 
                                     "Total"), 
                                   c("2.5 %", "97.5 %")))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: can i rename the column names and row names instead of factor(dummy1)0 just mention 0?

Comment: @datadigger see above;