# Combine multiple objects with different rows

Tags: r, object, matrix, types, cbind

I have the following objects:

```
> freq
    0     1       
11027  1264 12291 

> wf
                  total     SE
df[[var_name]]0 4327145  98763
df[[var_name]]1  691647  48336
Total           5018792 108969

> prop
                     mean        SE   DEff
df[[var_name]]0 0.8621886 0.0087937 8.0181
df[[var_name]]1 0.1378114 0.0087937 8.0181

> CI
                    2.5 %    97.5 %
df[[var_name]]0 0.8449534 0.8794239
df[[var_name]]1 0.1205761 0.1550466

> CV
df[[var_name]]0 df[[var_name]]1 
     0.01019923      0.06380940
```

I need to combine all of them into one table that contains all the columns of every object. Object **freq** and **wf** have 3 rows while others have 2 rows so in my final results I want a table with 3 rows where the last row would be blank for every object with 2 rows. My final results should look something like this:

[image]

here is the type of the object

```
library(survey) ## load this library for reproducibility 

> dput(freq)
c(`0` = 11027L, `1` = 1264L, 12291L)
> dput(wf)
structure(c(`df[[var_name]]0` = 4327145.41087343, `df[[var_name]]1` = 691646.58912879, 
Total = 5018792.00000222), class = "svystat", var = structure(c(9754076450.14318, 
-108168197.221403, 9645908252.92177, -108168197.221403, 2336411279.25803, 
2228243082.03663, 9645908252.92177, 2228243082.03663, 11874151334.9584
), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("df[[var_name]]0", "df[[var_name]]1", 
"Total"), c("df[[var_name]]0", "df[[var_name]]1", "Total"))), statistic = "total")
> dput(prop)
structure(c(`df[[var_name]]0` = 0.862188632418223, `df[[var_name]]1` = 0.137811367581777
), var = structure(c(7.73284606519557e-05, -7.73284606519557e-05, 
-7.73284606519557e-05, 7.73284606519557e-05), .Dim = c(2L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(c("df[[var_name]]0", "df[[var_name]]1"), 
    c("df[[var_name]]0", "df[[var_name]]1"))), statistic = "mean", class = "svystat", deff = structure(c(8.01805078282499, 
8.01805078282499, 8.01805078282499, 8.01805078282499), var = structure(c(4.05825805051452e-05, 
-4.05825805051452e-05, -4.05825805051452e-05, 4.05825805051452e-05, 
-4.05825805051452e-05, 4.05825805051452e-05, 4.05825805051452e-05, 
-4.05825805051453e-05, -4.05825805051452e-05, 4.05825805051452e-05, 
4.05825805051452e-05, -4.05825805051453e-05, 4.05825805051452e-05, 
-4.05825805051453e-05, -4.05825805051453e-05, 4.05825805051453e-05
), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("df[[var_name]]0", "df[[var_name]]0", 
"df[[var_name]]1", "df[[var_name]]1"), c("df[[var_name]]0", "df[[var_name]]0", 
"df[[var_name]]1", "df[[var_name]]1"))), statistic = "variance", class = c("svyvar", 
"svystat"), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("df[[var_name]]0", 
"df[[var_name]]1"), c("df[[var_name]]0", "df[[var_name]]1"))))
> dput(CI)
structure(c(0.844953375029307, 0.120576110192862, 0.879423889807138, 
0.155046624970693), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("df[[var_name]]0", 
"df[[var_name]]1"), c("2.5 %", "97.5 %")))
> dput(CV)
c(`df[[var_name]]0` = 0.010199230102026, `df[[var_name]]1` = 0.0638093969147096
)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `broom` package? It is designed to convert model objects of various types into tables. It's unclear from the question what type of model objects you have here.

Comment: Can you run `dput(freq)`, `dput(wf)`, etc. and include the output in your question? If the objects are too large, you might use the `butcher` package to remove extraneous elements (e.g. source data) before doing so. https://butcher.tidymodels.org/

Comment: Or can you show us some code to create model objects of similar type using standard data sets? As is, it's hard to help, since we don't have your objects, so we can't try out potential solutions.

Comment: @JonSpring added the dput() results to the question

Answer (score 1):

Same as your previous question: [Combine (binding columns) two objects with different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77517821/combine-binding-columns-two-objects-with-different-classes/77517988#77517988),

You need to convert to data.frame. Here, You also need to make them the same size, hence, `rbind`.

```
library(survey)

cbind(freq, 
      as.data.frame(wf), 
      rbind(as.data.frame(prop), NA),
      rbind(as.data.frame(CI), NA),
      rbind(as.data.frame(CV), NA))
#>    freq     total        SE      mean         SE     deff     2.5 %    97.5 %
#> 0 11027 4327145.4  98762.73 0.8621886 0.00879366 8.018051 0.8449534 0.8794239
#> 1  1264  691646.6  48336.44 0.1378114 0.00879366 8.018051 0.1205761 0.1550466
#>   12291 5018792.0 108968.58        NA         NA       NA        NA        NA
#>           CV
#> 0 0.01019923
#> 1 0.06380940
#>           NA
```